# Cost of LU decomposition (time cost)

Tags: computational-complexity, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination, lu-decomposition

After calculation of the cost of the steps of the LU decomposition, and we come to the end result:

$(2/3)n^3 - (2/3)n$  and we say the total cost is then $(2/3)n^3$ (ignoring the term $(-2/3)n$), could we conclude (or say) that the cost of the LU decomposition = $O(n^3)$? or is it $O( (2/3)n^3)$ and we HAVE to write the cost = $O( (2/3)n^3 )$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ignore the constant in big-O notation.  It would be $O(n^3)$.

Comment: Okay. So if I am asked about the total cost of the LU decomposition on an (n*n) Matrix, the right answer would be: O(n^3). Right?

Comment: Based on what you said above, yes.

Comment: Okay, perfect! Thank you for the help!